# Rails model scope and group

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, scope, group-by

I would like to get all users that have a registration stage of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6 and then group them in registration stages.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    scope :incomplete_onboarding, -> { where(registration_stage: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).group('registration_stage') }

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the ruby's `group_by` is a better option for what you want to accomplish, so you can remove the `group` from the scope

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    scope :incomplete_onboarding, -> { where(registration_stage: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) }

end
```

And then when you call it you can group it:

```
User.incomplete_onboarding.group_by { |u| u.registration_stage }
```

This will result in an hash like this

```
{ 1 => [user1, user2], 2 => [user3] }
```

Comment: Thank you, that works although I would like the scope to naturally serve the data in groups but maybe that isnt ideal.